# Facing build issue of CI pipeline in Teamcity

Tags: node.js, npm

We have application with code repository in BitBucket and it connect to TeamCity server for CI/CD pipelines which run and deployed our code to Azure cloud. There is a issue we are facing in CI pipelines to run. We are getting a build error a one step.

We unable to find the url(404 Not found)coming from in attached image. I'm new to this Teamcity usage.

Comment: Build errors
[15:53:34]Step 3/5: Install Node Dependencies for Grunt (Node.js NPM) (4s)
[15:53:34][Step 3/5] npm install (4s)
[15:53:38][npm install] npm ERR! fetch failed https://github.com/ariya/esprima/tarball/master

Comment: Thanks for your first contribution. To improve this question, please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - then edit your question. Show what you got, what you aim for, and what you get and make clear what your problem is.